# Arabic characters displays tangled in crystal reports

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

i am using crystal reports 13.13 for visual studio 2013
and i am creating a report that is in Arabic language

here is a screenshot of the right display

[image: right]

and this is the wrong display that appears to me

[image: wrong]

i tried using different fonts (arial unicode, times new roman ..etc) but the same result

please help

Comment: What is wrong with display?

Comment: accents!! nvm i got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it was due to that some data has accents (diacritics) in them which some how contaminated all the data

I solved it using the function posted here

[How do I remove diacritics (accents) from a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net)